# Temp Table existence check

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried the following code in SQL Server and met a strange error:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#t1') IS NULL
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE #t1(
    F1 DATE NOT NULL
)
END

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#t1') IS NULL
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE #t1(
    F1 DATE NOT NULL
)
END
```

Error:

> '#t1' existed.

I have no idea why this error occurs?

Comment: It seems like your IF clauses are being evaluated before your first create table is executed, if you put a GO statement after your first IF...END then you don't receive the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is idea

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#t1') IS NULL
BEGIN
   CREATE TABLE #t1( F1 DATE NOT NULL )
END
GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#t1') IS NULL
BEGIN
   CREATE TABLE #t1( F1 DATE NOT NULL )
END
GO
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I know 'GO' is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
IF NOT exists(SELECT 1
              FROM information_schema.columns 
              WHERE table_name LIKE '#t1%')
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE #t1(
    F1 DATE NOT NULL
)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
IF Not EXISTS (select * from sys.objects where Name = 'tempdb..#t1')

BEGIN
CREATE TABLE #t1(
    F1 DATE NOT NULL
)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not runtime Error, it's a "compiletime" error

```
--Drop table #t1  // call this alone to ensure that it's not existing, then call the rest, nothing will be printed

Print 0

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t1') IS NULL
BEGIN
Print 1
CREATE TABLE #t1(
    F1 DATE NOT NULL
)
END



IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t1') IS NULL
BEGIN
Print 2
CREATE TABLE #t1(
    F1 DATE NOT NULL
)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

- SQL Server does not store temp table with given name (`'#t1'`).
  Instead it adds a suffix to make it 128 character long. Therefore you
  won't find `'#t1'`.

You can use `LIKE '#t1%'` to find it.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select * from tempdb.sys.tables where name like '#t1%')
```

- Also you should add `GO` after your first query to mark the end of batch.

Use it as below;

```
--DROP TABLE #t1
--GO

    IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#t1') IS NULL
    BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #t1(
        F1 DATE NOT NULL
    )
    END
    GO

    IF NOT EXISTS(select * from tempdb.sys.tables where name like '#t1%')
    BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #t1(
        F1 DATE NOT NULL
    )
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is actually fine, but there's a limitation in SQL Server which means that during the query optimization phase it will fail. Please see the answers [here - why does sql server think a temp table already exists when it doesnt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828261/why-does-sql-server-thinks-a-temp-table-already-exists-when-it-doesnt).