Specify column name in a local variable
I would like to specify the column name of a table in a local variable to use it in a select statement. How can this be done? The following code does not output all values in the table for the column "salesprice" but just the name of the local variable @vprice.
declare @vprice varchar(10)
set @vprice = 'salesprice'
select @vprice from dbo.mydata


You can't. Only data values can be parameters. That's how SQL, the language, works. A query isn't executed as if it was a script. The database looks at the query, the tables and columns it uses, any indexes or data statistics and generates an execution plan that specifies which indexes will be used, whether data will be stored in temporary storage, whether to use parallel execution etc. It's impossible to generate an execution plan without knowing what the actual table or column is

Please note that building queries from outside can be a huge security hole. If you take column names from outside of your script, you could potentially be building SQL that gives attackers a way to take over your machine. This is what "SQL injection" is.

Which DBMS is this? Please tag your request accordingly.

I use SQL server from Microsoft

So now I've added the  tag, (The  tag is for general ANSI/ISO SQL, supported by dozens and dozens of products, which of SQL Server is just one. And the above code is product specific.)

Construct your query dynamically and execute it with exec (@sql)
declare @vprice varchar(10)
declare @SQL varchar(512)
set @vprice = 'salesprice'
SET  @SQL = 'SELECT ' +  Quotename(@vprice)  + ' FROM dbo.mydata'

exec (@SQL)

fiddle

One way to prevent SQL injection is to use QUOTENAME around variables. see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/170990/preventing-sql-injection-in-dynamic-sql

This works. Can I use @SQL as a derived table too?
e.g. select * from (@SQL)

@Georg Not exactly. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table

This seems closer to your scenario https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984918/insert-result-of-executing-dynamic-query-into-a-table

@BartMcEndree More like "One very weak way to prevent..."

While it's ugly and messy, the safest and most resilient is to first make sure the column exists, and also protect yourself from potential case sensitivity / collation issues. The following first makes sure the column exists and then takes its explicit name from sys.columns so that, if the collation is (or ever becomes) case sensitive, it still uses what's in the metadata as opposed to whatever the user decided to type.
DECLARE @weapon sysname = N'salesprice'; -- not varchar(10)!

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max), 
        @sch sysname = N'dbo',
        @tbl sysname = N'mydata';

SELECT @sql = CONCAT(N'SELECT ', QUOTENAME(c.name), N' FROM ',
              QUOTENAME(@sch), N'.', QUOTENAME(t.name), N';')
  FROM sys.tables AS t
 INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
    ON t.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
 WHERE t.name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS = @tbl
   AND c.name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS = @weapon;

PRINT @sql; -- will be invalid SQL if @weapon is wrong
--EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;

If I absolutely had to take user input and shove it into a statement, this is the way I'd handle it in my systems. (And if I needed to support entity names extending beyond Latin, I'd just use a more appropriate CI collation.)
If you want to prevent a runtime error, you can wrap the EXEC sys.sp_executesql call in:
IF NOT EXISTS 
( 
  SELECT 1 
    FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(@sql, NULL, 0)
   WHERE [error_number] IS NOT NULL
)
BEGIN
  EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
END


Yep. And to make sure it's obvious: this option uses the c.name value stored in the schema instead of the user-supplied @weapon directly, as well as t.name instead of @tbl. So the original input is also filtered through the schema definition. Not impossible to do injection this way in the right (well: wrong!) situations, but it does add another layer to get through.
